# Creating a year/week format for current date in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm writing this post because I could find no other thread where the question was already answered.

What could be the best code to create a "y/w" format (y being a 2-digits year and w a 2 digits week number) in R?
So far, this is what I'm using:

```
require(lubridate)
paste(substr(year(Sys.Date()),3,4),sprintf("%02d", isoweek(Sys.Date())), sep="/")
```

But of course this could fail on the last days of the year or in the first ones; for example, it could give a "16/53" outcome for January, 1 of 2016 (while it should be "16/01").

I'm thinking about some if-else construct based on `Sys.Date` being higher or lower than January 1st and combining it with `wday` function, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant and concise solution.

Do you have any clue on that?
Thanks,
MZ

Comment: What about `format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%U")`?

Comment: almost lovely. Changed it to `format(Sys.Date(), "%y/%U"` but it shows that today is still w7, while it should be w8... This is the reason why I'm using `isoweek` instead of `week` in the lubricate package.

Comment: I see. Hmmm however, `isoweek(as.Date("2016-01-01"))` is `53`, not `1`. Is that what you want? Because in this case, I'd just modify the `isoweek` function to return the year, too.

Comment: I want `15/53`, because it's the 53rd week of 2015. 
If you try with `isoweek(as.Date(2015-01-01))` you see that in that case it's the 1st week, so my could would work fine (just as it works fine up to December 31st 2015).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to adjust `lubridate::isoweek` to return the desired string:

```
isodate <- function (x = Sys.Date()) {
  xday <- ISOdate(year(x), month(x), day(x), tz = tz(x))
  dn <- 1 + (wday(x) + 5)%%7
  nth <- xday + ddays(4 - dn)
  jan1 <- ISOdate(year(nth), 1, 1, tz = tz(x))
  return(sprintf("%s/%02d", format(nth, "%y"), 1 + (nth - jan1)%/%ddays(7)))
}
isodate(as.Date("2016-01-01"))
# [1] "15/53"
isodate(as.Date("2015-01-01"))
# [1] "15/01"
isodate(Sys.Date())
# [1] "15/08"
```

Comment: wow lukeA, this exceeds a little bit my coding skills, and I will spend some minutes to learn more about your solution; nonetheless, this is more or less my intended backup solution (working on the 1st of January weekday), but so far I'm really puzzled about why such a "common" (?) useful function hasn't been already solved in some package or haven't been already asked. Am I the only one interested in a ISO version of year and week?

Comment: Good thing about R: enter a functions name - in this case `isoweek` - and you get its source code printed. Then I just modified it a bit so that it returns your desired result. The code itself exceeds my "coding skills" probably more than yours.... ;-)

Comment: lol, right. I didn't think to have a look at the function!!! :-)  
Thanks a lot, Luke!

Answer (score 7):

If you're here in 2018, try [yearweek](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsibble/versions/0.5.2/topics/yearweek) from tsibble

```
library(tsibble)
library(tidyverse)

my_date <- "2018-01-01"

yearweek(my_date) %>% 
  str_replace(" W", "/") %>% 
  str_replace("^20", "")

#> [1] 17/52
```

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: alternatively using `format.yearweek`, like `format(tsibble::yearweek("20180101"), "%V/%y")`

Answer (score 2):

Using **lubridate** package function `isoyear()` combined with `isoweek()`, it is possible to obtain one-line answer to your question.

```r
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

dates <- ymd(c("2016-01-01", "2015-12-31", "2015-01-01"))

# check dates[1] and dates[2] are in the same week
wday(dates)
#> [1] 6 5 5

str_c(
  formatC(isoweek(dates), format = "f", digits = 0, width = 2, flag = "0"), 
  "/", 
  str_sub(isoyear(dates), 3, 4))
#> [1] "53/15" "53/15" "01/15"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Replace `isoweek()` with `week()`, a function from lubridate.

```
> paste(substr(year(x),3,4),sprintf("%02d", week(x)), sep="/")
[1] "16/01"
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but I really need `isoweek`. As I commented above, `week` would give me a "7" for today's date, but this monday is the first day of the 8th ISO week ...