# R Date yyyy-ww in Highcharter stock shiny

Tags: r, date, week-number, r-highcharter

I'm working on epidemiological data with specific date format, yyyy-ww i.e 2021-32, 32nd weeks of the year 2021. How to use this specific format yyyy-ww as a proper Date format (to be used in Highcharter stock in R Shiny.

Comment: The `lubridate` poackage is likely to be helpful.  for example, [here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/week.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a year/week format for current date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543243/creating-a-year-week-format-for-current-date-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `year_week` from `lares` package

```
year_week(date)
```

Or perhaps `yearweek` from `tsibble` package could be an option

```
yearweek(df$date)
```

Comment: The year_week, works but provides a character string. I would need to use yyyy-ww as a Date format. class(qq<-year_week("2021-04-24"))

Comment: Where does `year_week()` come from?

Comment: Hi @harre, from the `lares` package

Comment: all the output from lares and tsibble provide as an ouput a character format not a Date format that could be used for epidemiological time series analysis purpose